# Can I uninstall ufw if using iptables?

Tags: iptables, ufw

*OS: Linux Mint 18.2 Cinnamon 64-bit*

Let's start with the status of `ufw`:

```
sudo ufw status
```

says:

> ```
> Status: inactive
> ```

Hence, I suppose, in spite there is connection between `ufw` and `iptables`, if I am using `iptables` for controlling open ports, etc., I do not need it.

Is this assumption correct, and I can freely purge `ufw` from my systems?

Or is there any reason on keeping it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ufw is just a frontend for iptables. It can be removed anytime, and i think this is the right way. The best way is to not install it at all.